# First time Updating a table

Tags: sql-update, sql-insert

I was recently given permissions to update a single table in our database but this is not something I have done before and I do not what to mess anything up. I have tried searching for something online that was similar to what I am wanting to do with no success.

The table name is dbo.Player_Miles and it only has two columns of data Player_ID and Miles both of which are set as (int,null).

Currently there are about 300K records in this table and I have a csv file I need to use to update this table. In the file there are 500k Records so I need to be able to:

INSERT the new records ~250k records

UPDATE the records with that have new information ~200K records

Leave untouched and record that has the same information(although updating those to the same thing would not hurt the database would be a resource hog I would guess) ~50K records

Also leave untouched any records in the table currently that are not in the updated file. ~50k records

I am using SSMS 2008 but the Server is 2000.

Comment: It is a very simple job to backup your database and restore it to a different instance. You can then practice all you like until you are sure of your process before trying your script live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this in stages...

1) Backup the database

2) Create a temporary SQL table to hold your update records

```
create table Player_Miles_Updates (
    PlayerId int not null,
    Miles int null)
```

3) Load the records from your text file into your temporary table

```
bulk insert Player_Miles_Updates
   from 'c:\temp\myTextRecords.csv'
   with
     (
        FIELDTERMINATOR =' ,',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
      )
```

4) Begin a transaction

```
begin transaction
```

5) Insert your new data

```
insert  into Player_Miles
select  PlayerId, Miles
from    Player_Miles_Updates
where   PlayerId not in (select PlayerId from Player_Miles)
```

6) Update your existing data

```
update  Player_Miles
set     Player_Miles.Miles = pmu.Miles
from    Player_Miles pm join Player_Miles_Updates pmu on pm.Player_Id = pmu.Player_Id
```

7) Select a few rows to make sure what you wanted to happen, happened

```
select  *
from    Player_Miles
where   Player_Id in (1,45,86,14,83) -- use id's that you have seen in the csv file
```

8a) If all went well

```
commit transaction
```

8b) If all didn't go well

```
rollback transaction
```

9) Delete the temporary table

```
drop table Player_Miles_Updates
```

Comment: This seems like what I want so I am testing it now. Although I had a question on step 2 if we are making a temp table should it not have # in front of the name

Comment: Yes, you could use '#' in front. That would make it a truly temporary table (ie. one that will disappear if you close the window you are working in).

Comment: When I did step 3 I got the following error    Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Line 6: Incorrect syntax near '\n'.

Comment: opps ignore that I forgot to highlight the ) when I tried to run it but now I have an error stating the current user is not the database or object owner of table #Player_Miles_Updates cannot perform set operation

Comment: Personally, I'd use a normal table (dont prefix with '#') and then delete it once I was done with it.

Comment: I don't know if I have the access to create a normal table. Our DB Admin does not like to give out rights to anything. I normally just run select statements to pull data. However we recently needed to add this Player_Miles table so he did that and when he found out that I was going to need it updated weekly he decided to give me insert update and delete powers for just this table which is almost unheard of from him.

Comment: Guess I will have to try using a regular table as apparently my issue stems from the fact that SQL 2000 will not let you do Bulk insert into a temp table. So how do I delete just this table when I am done.

Comment: Dang as I expected the permission is denied to create a real table. So I guess my only other option is to then just delete out all records from the Player_Miles table and just add in the new file and deal with the loss of a few records. The new file "should" have everything we need each time anyways keeping the old info was more of just wishful thinking I guess to try and cut down on some other work in the future

Answer (score 1):

You should use SSIS (or DTS, which was replaced by SSIS in SQL Server 2005).
Use the CSV as your source and "upsert" the data to your destination table.

In SSIS there are different ways to get this task done.

An easy way would be to use a lookup task on Player_ID.
If there's a match update the value and if there's no match just insert the new value.

[See this link for more informations on lookup-pattern-upsert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/11/22/lookup-pattern-upsert.aspx)

Comment: I also like this idea and will look at it in the future but right now I have no idea about how to use SSIS as I am still very new to SQL and only really know a few basic things about SSMS.